# How do I create a View with a variable number of Subviews in SwiftUI?

Tags: arrays, view, swiftui

I have two arrays with different numbers of elements and want to display each of this elements in different subviews. So that the user has to tab "next" and the next element of the array is displayed until he/she is at the end of the array.

It should work like this:

```
         ---FirstView(FirstElement)---SecondView(SecondElement)---ThirdView(ThirdElement)--Close
Mainview
         ---FirstView(FirstElement)---SecondView(SecondElement)--Close
```

So the number of Views I need is variable. But I don't know how this can be done and can't find something like this.

My code is the following

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showPopover: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
                    self.showPopover.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Choose a Usergroup")
                }.sheet(isPresented: $showPopover) {
                    NewView(showPopover: $showPopover)
                }
    }
}

struct NewView: View {
    @Binding var showPopover: Bool
    @State var namesOfFemaleUsers = ["Sabrina", "Nicole", "Barbara"]
    @State var namesOfMaleUsers = ["Peter", "Bart", "Homer", "Bernie", "Carl"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: VariableView(showPopover: $showPopover, arrayData: namesOfMaleUsers),
                    label: {
                        Text("Male Users")
                    })
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: VariableView(showPopover: $showPopover, arrayData: namesOfFemaleUsers),
                    label: {
                        Text("Female Users")
                    })
            }

        }
    }
}

struct VariableView: View {
    @Binding var showPopover: Bool
    @State var arrayData: [String]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
//         Here should be a Text with the name of first element and a button to go to the next View with the second element
            Button(action: {self.showPopover.toggle()}){
                Text("Close")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible approach, just operate with indexes of available data, checking range for safety.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
struct NewView: View {
    @Binding var showPopover: Bool
    var namesOfFemaleUsers = ["Sabrina", "Nicole", "Barbara"]
    var namesOfMaleUsers = ["Peter", "Bart", "Homer", "Bernie", "Carl"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                if !namesOfMaleUsers.isEmpty {
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: VariableView(showPopover: $showPopover, arrayData: namesOfMaleUsers, index: 0),
                        label: {
                            Text("Male Users")
                        })
                }
                if !namesOfFemaleUsers.isEmpty {
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: VariableView(showPopover: $showPopover, arrayData: namesOfFemaleUsers, index: 0),
                        label: {
                            Text("Female Users")
                        })
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

struct VariableView: View {
    @Binding var showPopover: Bool
    var arrayData: [String]
    var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("User: \(arrayData[index])")
            if index + 1 < arrayData.count {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: VariableView(showPopover: $showPopover, arrayData: arrayData, index: index + 1),
                    label: {
                        Text("Next")
                    })
            }
            Button(action: {self.showPopover.toggle()}){
                Text("Close")
            }
        }
    }
}
```